# How to retrieve the selected option of a select nested in a <td>

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a loop that runs through all the table data. It works great for pulling "text here" string from html markup like "`<td>text here</td>`", but I have nested elements in some cells like "`<td><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select><label>some other string</label></td>`"

This is the code I am trying to use to grab the selected option from the select element.

```
$(this).children().eq(0).find("option:selected");
```

The select element is the first element nested inside the `<td></td>` that is why it is `children().eq(0)`

`$(this)` is a `<td>...</td>`

I was hoping `.find("option:selected");` would retrieve the selected option but it is not valid code.

Here is a structural example of what a common `<td>` tag contains:

```
<td><select><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option></select><label>some other string</label></td>
```

I want the selected option for the first select tag in a td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `val()` method to get the selected option's value.

```
var val = $(this).find("select").eq(0).val();
```

With the assumption that `$(this)` is the `td` element in your context, in which you have the select element.

Comment: Perfect! That works great. For me too, it returns 0 if a selection has not been made so I can validate the select and tell users to make a selection because they have not made one. Thanks!